# Reading from S7-1500PLC with s7.net and convert to c# compatible data type

Tags: c#, plc, siemens

I can read the result from the siemens S7-1500 PLC but not sure how to convert it.

I have below code in c#

```
var lowSpeedSwing = (uint)Plc.Read("DB85.DBD50");
```

The data type is REAL in PLC.  The result return something like 59864324.  How I can cast the result?  I try the code below but not sure it's correct or not.

```
var lowSpeedSwing = ((uint)Plc.Read("DB85.DBD50")).ConvertToFloat();
```

it gave me 0.5 but not sure it's correct answer.  I read S7 documentation and the example provide as below

```
//Read S7 Real, you need to use ConvertToDouble():
double result = ((uint)plc.Read("DB1.DBD40")).ConvertToDouble();
```

But I can't find ConvertToDouble, I only able use ConvertToFloat().

I'm new in Communicate with Siemens PLC using c#.  Please show me a direction, Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using standard C# conversion methods such as `double result = (double)plc.Read("DB1.DBD40");` or `float result = (float)plc.Read("DB1.DBD40");` ?

Comment: I try it but it's throw me casting error.

Comment: What's the error message? The method indicated in the answer below is another excelent way, but sometimes what is happening is that an unexpected value comes from the reading (`NULL` for example) which is causing the error in the conversion, then you could try to use a try/cath or a TryParse

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it in a different way.

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble((uint)plc.Read("DB1.DBD40"));
```

Furthermore it is also possible to make a model with your entire datablock in it to convert a lot of values more easy.

https://www.mesta-automation.com/siemens-s7-plc-c-s7-net-plc-driver/

Here is a good explanation.

Edit: personally I found Sharp7 library a lot more easy to understand if you don't mind what you use